# How to transfer or remove data synchronization with Redux-persist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Made an authorization application. After a successful login, data is written to AsyncStorage.
I need to access data through shared storage. How to transfer or remove data synchronization with Redux-persist?

Answer (score 0):

Redux-persist have blacklist and whitelist, if your value in backlist it won't be persisted ( whitelist is opposite).